# Is it possible to provision Android app configuration after packaging

Tags: android

Is there a way to provision the configuration of an Android application AFTER it is packaged?

To be more specific here a scenario when this can be useful:

A vendor company (Vendor) is developing an application that works with some (non-cloud) systems that are usually hosted internally by customers ... for example Exchange server.

A Customer purchases this application and wants to configure it for their landscape - configure hosts of the servers, add certificates for the ssl connections etc.

Is there a STANDARD way to provision this configuration during the installation? Let's say that the application uses standard SharedPreferences and the IT department just "enriches" the APK before deploying it on the devices with some values that are specific for their landscape?

Thank you

Vasil

Comment: You can prompt them to choose settings on first time run (after install), that get stored in sharedpreferences, if thats what you mean.

Comment: Mmm ... yes - this could work but is not what I meant.
Imagine that you have to hand out 500 sales people with an application that is somehow useful for them but needs to be configured to use your internal CRM system. 
You could write a documentation about this and ask them to follow it but since salesman are usually far away from technical details it is very likely that they don't do it right.
On the other side it will be very inconvenient for the IT staff to configure 500 devices manually. 
It would be nice to just get the APK, "push" some file to it and make it the default config.

Comment: you could quite easily pass defaults, and just change those necessary as you suggest in the "encriches" process. And theres not much difference in doing it in first time load up, compared to during the install. Someones going to need to tailor it at some point, if it differs for different users. Unless you parse a file with the info, but who creates that needs to tailor that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the apk package as it is signed. So your only option is to deliver configuration externally or to package application with the right configuration.

If your customers have their own infrastructure and your app operate with it. Think about custom build for each client.

If your application is an addition to existing well known software made by 3rd party. And you assume that there will be a lot of customers then first option is not what you want. So you can pass some configuration in URL used to install application. Look at [this](http://www.localytics.com/docs/android-market-campaign-analytics/)